# Strange C++ exception "definition"

Tags: c++, exception

A student of mine submitted some C++ code similar to the following one. The code compiles and runs, but the `throw` statement produces the following message:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'

If I make the function `void` the compiler complains

> invalid use of ‘void’

on the line that contains the `throw` statement (expectedly).

```
class TestClass
{
public:
    int MyException()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    void testFunc()
    {
        throw MyException();
    }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    TestClass tc;
    tc.testFunc();

    return 0;
}
```

*So, how does C++ interpret `MyException` since the code is "correct" ?*

Comment: The way unhandled exceptions are reported varies by implementation, platform, etc. My guess (hence the comment) is that it's just saying "I got this exception here and it's just an int so I don't have any more information for you"

Comment: When you throw something, you need to catch it or it will crash on your head.

Comment: A student turned this in and you don't know what it does??  Kudos for you coming here and asking but man, I really hated teachers like you when I was in college.  Of course, when I talked with one of my old professors about teaching C++ at their college he asked me to teach C#.  When I said I didn't know the language it didn't deter him one bit.  So I guess knowledge isn't really a prerequisite for teaching anymore...if it ever was.

Comment: Teachers can't know everything, and they may also ask to learn more.

My knowledge of C++ may be getting a bit rusty, but I hope you agree that this is not an expected way of throwing an exception. To me it is similar to the more classic `List x;` vs `List x();`.

The student should have defined an exception class, but instead produced this, which puzzled me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It calls the function: `MyException()`, then throws the returned `int`. A more complete example:

```
struct foo
{
    int bar(void) const
    {
        return 123456789;
    }

    void baz(void) const
    {
        throw bar();
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    try
    {
        foo f;
        f.baz(); // throws exception of type int, caught below
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        // i is 123456789
    }
}
```

Without the try-catch block, the exception propagates out of main, where `terminate()` is called.

Note that throwing things that don't derive from `std::exception` is frowned upon. It's expected that you be able to catch meaningful exceptions by `catch (const std::exception&)`.

Comment: The answer is in the first line. Actually `throw` needs an object, and the object is the `int` returned by the function...

Thanks to everyone about the comments on `terminate`, but this was not part of the question, of course the exception was unhandled.

Answer (score 2):

The program terminated because the exception was not caught. Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    try
    {
        TestClass tc; 
        tc.testFunc(); 
    }
    catch(int)
    {
    }

    return 0; 
}
```