# Why am I getting an error when I try to use my structure?

Tags: c++, structure

I have a structure Defined in the Header file for a class i am working in, and i am trying to use the Struct in one of the methods of the class. It looks basically like this:

```
struct example
{
     double a;
     int b;
     ...
};
```

in the header above my class definition, and then in the cpp file, i have:

```
void exampleclass::test(){

    struct example *teststruct;
    teststruct->a = 0; //This line causes a access violation

}
```

why do i get an error here? Im sure im doing something clompletly wrong here, and i must say im a huge structure rookie.

Comment: You should get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn properly.

Comment: @Gman - at least he isn't [teaching a course](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311006/strange-c-exception-definition "teaching a course")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about allocating the memory for your structure ?

something like :

```
example* teststruct = new example;
teststruct->a = 0;
```

Comment: This worked. dont know why I thought I diddnt need to allocate the memory.

Comment: This. Ben, you declared a pointer but didn't point it at an instance of the struct.

Comment: @Ben: A pointer has to point at something if you want to use what it's pointing to. Of course, there's no reason to use a pointer here.

Comment: @Ben313 you thought so because you never thought that your inside a class :)

Answer (score 4):

`struct example *teststruct;` is a pointer to an instance of the struct `example`. (By the way, C++ does not require the `struct` prefix, leave it off.)

So, what `example` are you pointing at? (Hint: none, you haven't initialized the variable.) You could dynamically allocate one: `example *teststruct = new example();`, and later delete it: `delete teststruct;`.*

Of course, you should prefer automatic (stack) allocation over dynamic allocation, and just do:

```
example teststruct;
teststruct.a = 0;
```

<sub>*And you should never actually handle raw allocations like this. Put them in a smart pointer. At the very least, `std::auto_ptr`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

As you've written it `teststruct` points to some random location in memory so accessing it, by doing `teststruct->a = 0;` takes you into undefined behavior land. So you can have - if you're really lucky - an instant error [like access violation, bus error, segmentation fault etc]  or it will run without problems.

You need to either allocate memory for `teststruct` like Max said or create it on the stack and do something like:

```
struct example teststruct;
teststruct.a = 0; //This line does not cause an access violation
```